# Converting a substring to an Int in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, int, substring

```
List<Book> myLibrary = new ArrayList <Book>(312); 
public BookLibrary (Scanner inFile){
    while(inFile.hasNextLine()){
     String aBook = inFile.nextLine();
     String title = aBook.substring(0, 32).trim();
     String language = aMovie.substring(33, 40).trim();
     String rating = aMovie.substring(41, 50).trim();
     int hardCover = Integer.parseInt(aBook.substring(51, 55).trim()); 
     int paperBack = Integer.parseInt(aBook.substring(56));
     myLibrary.add(new  Book (title, language, rating,
     hardCover, paperBack));
     count++;
    }
```

Just some example code here. I am trying to figure out why I am receiving this runtime error when I attempt to run my program. I have no compiler errors in my program.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at MovieCollection.<init>(BookLibrary.java:21)
```

Comment: seems like one of the strings is empty. you should check for nulls and empty strings before trying to parse them into a number. you could debug and see what aBook contains and if the 51-55 and 56-inf are valid strings for a number

Comment: You are not allowed to remove the content of your question when users have already contributed answers to it.

Answer (score 1):

Either there is error in format of the file (some values are missing) or error in indexes (params of **substring** methods) correct this method calls to appropriate:

```
substring(51, 55)
substring(56)
```

now one of them returns an empty string.

if hardCower or papperBack can be empty use **try/catch** construction:

```
int hardCover = 0;
int paperBack = 0;
try{
  hardCover = Integer.parseInt(aBook.substring(51, 55).trim());
}catch(NumberFormatException nfe){}

try{
  paperBack = Integer.parseInt(aBook.substring(56));
}catch(NumberFormatException nfe){}
```

or make check

```
String toInt1 = aBook.substring(51, 55).trim();
if(toInt1.length > 0){
  hardCover = Integer.parseInt(toInt1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a runtime exception, not a compiler error.

Problem occurs at one of the following lines -

```
 int hardCover = Integer.parseInt(aBook.substring(51, 55).trim()); 
 int paperBack = Integer.parseInt(aBook.substring(56));
```

One the arguments is an empty string `""`.

`Integer.parseInt` method can only handle a string with a valid integer. e.g. `"1"`, `"123"` are good, but `""` is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

One of the arguments to parseInt is `""`.

From the Javadoc of Integer.parseInt:

An exception of type NumberFormatException is thrown if any of the following situations occurs:

1. **The first argument is null or is a string of length zero.**
2. The radix is either smaller than java.lang.Character.MIN_RADIX or larger than java.lang.Character.MAX_RADIX.
3. Any character of the string is not a digit of the specified radix, except that the first character may be a minus sign '-' ('\u002D') provided that the string is longer than length 1.
4. The value represented by the string is not a value of type int.